# Trying to enable mouse events in my game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, mouseevent, keyboard-events

Game currently has keyboard enabled events . Tried changing it to mouse, but need help in it.

My code is as follows:

```
public function SetUp()
{ 
    hero=new Hero;addChild(hero);
    hero.x=400;hero.y=500;hero.dead=false;
    scorebox=new ScoreBox;addChild(scorebox);
    scorebox.x=25;scorebox.y=12;
    score=0;
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyDownHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUpHandler);
    BulletArray= new Array;EnemyArray= new Array;
    timer.start();
}//setup
enter code here
public function KeyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent){
        //trace(e.keyCode);
        if(e.keyCode==39){Right=true;}
        if(e.keyCode==37){Left=true;}
        }//keydown

    public function KeyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent){
        if(e.keyCode==39){Right=false;}
        if(e.keyCode==37){Left=false;}
        if(e.keyCode==32){Space=true;}
        }//keyup
enter code here
```

//to process user input used the following function

```
            public function ProcessUserInput(){
            if(Right && hero.x<780){hero.x+=5;}
            if(Left && hero.x>20){hero.x-=5;}
            if(Space){Shoot();}
        }//Process User Input
```

///I have written my mouse controlled code. but i cant seem to enable it in my present code

//the code for mouse control is as follows 
//need help incorporating it in my main class code .

```
enter code here
var leftDown:Boolean = false;
var upDown:Boolean = false;
var rightDown:Boolean = false;
var downDown:Boolean = false;



stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveCharMouse);


mcMain.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void{
    if(leftDown){
        mcMain.x -= 5;
    }
    if(upDown){
        mcMain.y -= 5;
    }
    if(rightDown){
        mcMain.x += 5;
    }
    if(downDown){
        mcMain.y += 5;
    }
    if(mcMain.x <= 0){
        mcMain.x += 5;
    }
    if(mcMain.y <= 0){
        mcMain.y += 5;
    }
    if(mcMain.x >= stage.stageWidth - mcMain.width){
        mcMain.x -= 5;
    }
    if(mcMain.y >= stage.stageHeight - mcMain.height){
        mcMain.y -= 5;
    }

}

function moveCharMouse(event:MouseEvent){
    mcMain.x = stage.mouseX - mcMain.width/2;
    mcMain.y = stage.mouseY - mcMain.height/2;
}
```

Comment: What is it that you need help with? You don't have any mouse-related code in your code.

Comment: In the future, you shouldn't put code in the comments.  Put it in the question, and format it.  That'll help people help you. :)

Comment: need help to change keyboard even to mouse event

Comment: Ok, this is horrible. 1. You can edit your post - stop posting compressed chunks of code into the comment section. 2. As xxbbcc hinted: Ask specific questions - what does your code (I currently don't read due to it being in an obfuscated state) do so far and what does it not do? Where exactly do you need help? 3. What are these classes you pasted about? Are they part of an API? Did you write them yourself and if yes: What do they look like?

Comment: they are part of my main class. i want to convert it to mouse controlled from the present keyboard control

Comment: i need help trying to make the above code respond to my mouse control rather than my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is a mess. The problem might be because you are not importing mouse events but since you dont show the imports and you dont tell us what your problem is like: "im getting the error..." or "my mouse event is not working". You dont even show us what mcMain is, how are we ment to help you?

Comment: Please use comments for such answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would write all of these separate "Controllers" into reusable classes and pass the sage reference to them.  From there you can set up the stage scope handler from inside each class.  Each class is organized, only holds its includes and variables, and can be self terminating.  Classic encapsulation.

Comment: Please use comments for such answers